# single download file for multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net

I have a website on which I have published several of my applications.
Right now I have to update it each time one of the applications is updated.
The applications themselves check for updates so the user only visits the website if they don't have a previous version installed.

I would like to make it easier for me by creating a single executable that when downloaded and executed, will check with the database which version is the most recent and then download that one and run that setup.

Now I can make a downloader for each application, but I rather make something more universal with a parameter or argument as the difference.

For the download the 'know' which database to check for the most recent version, I need to pass on the data to the downloader.
My first thought was putting that in a XML file, so I only have to generate different xml files for each application, but then it wouldn't be a single executable anymore.

My second thought was using commandline arguments like: downloader.exe databasename

But how would I do that when the file is downloaded?

Would a link like:  "https://my.website.com/downloader.exe databasename" work?

How could I best do this?

rg.
Eric

Comment: To keep it a single application download you can place the additional information into resources. Resources are part of the binary and can be updated after the binary has been created (see [Resource Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468907.aspx)). After you compiled your download binary you can modify the respective resources without having to recompile the binary. Writing a tool to automate this process is fairly straightforward as well.

Comment: It's not clear at what point the user selects which application they want. eg Why can't they just download downloader.exe and then have that ask them which app? Also, have you considered ClickOnce for this?